# Starting a ContentObserver on phone boot

Tags: android

I am using a `Broadcast Receiver` to receive a Broadcast when the phone boots up, and from there I'd like to register a `PhoneStateListener` and `ContentObserver`. Unfortunately it won't let me use the `setReceiver()` method for the `ContentObserver` like in my main activity. There was a similar problem with `PhoneStateListener` and `startService()`, but I was able to use the passed `context` to make it work. This does not solve the problem for `setReceiver`. What is the correct way of calling this method?

By the way the error it gives is "The method setReceiver(SmsObserver) is undefined for the type Context"

My code:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;

    // Get the telephony manager
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            // Create a new PhoneStateListener
            PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        Intent update = new Intent(mContext,
                                UpdateService.class);
                        mContext.startService(update);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataActivity(int direction) {
                    if (direction == TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE) {
                        Intent update = new Intent(mContext,
                                UpdateService.class);
                        mContext.startService(update);
                    }
                }
            };

            // Register the listener with the telephony manager
            telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            telephonyManager.listen(listener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY);

            SmsObserver smsSentObserver = new SmsObserver(new Handler(), mContext);

            //Unable to call this method
            mContext.setReceiver(smsSentObserver);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This does not solve the problem for setReceiver. What is the correct way of calling this method?

Tactically, there is no `setReceiver()` method anywhere in Android. If `SmsObserver` is supposed to be a `ContentObserver`, you would use a `ContentResolver` and `notifyChange()` to register it.

Strategically, your code is useless, as your process can be terminated shortly after `onReceive()` ends, making all this work moot.

Comment: Is it able to be terminated because I am running it in a BroadcastReceiver or does this apply to Activities too? I have used the same bit of code in onCreate in my main activity and haven't noticed the ContentObserver stopping after any length of time. It is observing the sent SMS box and refreshing my widget in onChange(), as it is terminated on shutdown I am attempting to start it again when the phone boots.

Comment: @MattHarris: "Is it able to be terminated because I am running it in a BroadcastReceiver or does this apply to Activities too?" -- if you are not in the foreground, Android will eventually terminate your process.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle